# When should I create a service for a class?

Tags: services

It seems that in Drupal code anything that is neither hook nor Plugin nor Controller nor any other thing with a standard functionality should be a **Service**.

For sure, services make sense when we want to give other modules the possibility to change the functionality that we are writing.

But I can think of a lot of scenarios where it is absolutely sufficient to have a normal class. When we just want to create an instance, call a method, nothing else.

How can I decide if a class is sufficient, or if a service makes sense?

**Edit** This is not opinion based. There must be a clear and objective reason why we use services in Drupal, and I want to know this reason.

Comment: I think this will probably be closed as opinion based (there isn't really a way to give an objective, correct answer), but some related reading: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251111/when-should-i-create-a-service-or-a-utility-function, https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8

Comment: It's really up to the code author intent. When you're looking to create globally-available, encapsulated black-box functionality, that may depend on other services it's a good sign that you might want to create a service. Re: Service class vs "normal" class, it helps to think about what you're encapsulating. A service class is encapsulating functionality that a service provides whereas a "normal" class (e.g. Node) is encapsulating some data along with functionality to act upon it. It might help to read up on SOA to get a better grasp of the design paradigm.

Comment: For me the main difference is that a service is by default a singleton staying in memory the entire request. So the scope of a service is global while a class instance you create is local.

Comment: @NoSssweat, Hehe, the question is slightly different, however, *your* answer to that question is very good, and it helps me a lot. Thank you!